# Is is possible to show the keyboard shortcut for a menu item in the HUD?

Tags: shortcut-keys, hud

When using the HUD I think it would be very useful if it displayed the keyboard shortcut for a menu item (if it has one). For example **New Tab** in Firefox has the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

[image]

Can the HUD be configured to show whether a menu item has a keyboard shortcut, something like the mock-up below:

[image]

Comment: I don't believe so.  I also believe this would be better served as a wishlist bug against the unity package

Comment: @aking1012 Yes you're right, I thought it might just be an option I'd missed, there is already a bug listed with a fix committed so this function is already on its way: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/921546

Comment: perhaps you can either post that as an answer and close the question or delete the question?  i'm more inclined to think accepting it as an answer is a better solution so people not acquainted with launchpad can find it is the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this function is not yet available in the HUD at the time of asking this question. The functionality has been proposed as a bug on Launchpad here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/921546

The bug has been confirmed and a fix committed so this functionality should appear within the HUD in a future update.

Comment: Doesn't look like this bug has been updated since 2012. Will it ever make it in?